# Problem accessing elements loaded from jQuery load()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I wanted to use the jQuery load() method to be able to reuse the same navbar html for multiple pages. The problem is that I can't access individual elements within the navbar html after it is loaded (I want to be able to select a navbar item and add an 'active' class). Doesn't even work when I try to do this in the load() callback. The 'active' class does not toggle on the selected element when I run this code.

If I try to select a navbar element using getElementById, it returns 'null.' This also doesn't work if I pass the callback as the second argument. It almost seems as if the callback is running before the html is loaded, but not sure why that would be the case.

JS:

```
function activate(){


 $(function(){
    $("#rebates").toggleClass('active');
})
}

$(function(){
$("footer").load("footer.html");
$(".navbar").load('navbar.html', null, activate()) })
```

It's loading the following html:

```
<div class='logoText'><h2>Logo</h2></div>    
<div class="navlinks" id='navlinks'>
   <ul>
       <li><a href="index.html"><span id='home'>Home</span></a></li>
       <li><a href="policies.html"><span id='policies'>Policies</span></a></li>
       <li><a href="rebates.html"><span id='rebates'>Rebates</span></a></li>
       <li><a href="contact.html"><span id='products'>Products</span></a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: In the `.load()` call, `activate()` should be `activate` without the `()`. The way it is now, you're calling the function *before* calling `.load()`.

Comment: Also you are adding a page load event handler in your activate.You just want `function activate() { $("#rebates").toggleClass('active'); }`

Comment: Thank you to Pointy. This solves my problem!